# dashDB: insert into generated default column using select

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, db2-luw, dashdb

I have a simple test table

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
KEY INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
INTENTS VARCHAR(255),
NO_FOUND SMALLINT );
```

I am then trying to insert data into this table using the following command from within dashDB's sql dashboard.

```
Insert into table from (select item1,item2,item3 from TEST2 where some_condition );
```

However I cannot seem to get the command to not return an error. 
Have tried the db2 'DEFAULT', and '0' (default for integer), and even NULL as values for item1.

Have also tried the insert using values, but then the column headings cause the system to report multiple values returned.

Have also tried 'OVERRIDING USER VALUE' 
but this then complains about not finding a JOIN element.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: and this error is....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
Insert into test(intents,no_found)
(select item2,item3 from TEST2 where some_condition );
```

You specify that only two of the three columns receive values, the KEY column is generated. Hence you only select the two related columns.

Comment: I have found this to work, however, I had originally tried
INSERT INTO TEST(INTENTS,NO_FOUND) VALUES (SELECT item2,item3 from TEST2 where some_condition); 
And this  had failed. 
After playing with this, about 10 minutes  after posting the question I also found that leaving the VALUES off the command allowed it to work, i.e. The command you have above.

Still does not answer why the DEFAULT values do not work, as they would in db2.

Comment: I looked over the syntax here http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000970.html Did you use GENERATED BY DEFAULT or GENERATED ALWAYS?

Comment: I used GENERATED BY DEFAULT .. the values of KEY are being created by the system correctly, i.e. 1,2,3,4,5, etc .. when I do a load via a csv file. But if I try an insert and use 'NULL' or DEFAULT, or 0 as the value for KEY - and thus have it create the correct next value, I get an error. DEFAULT is not understood, NULL is not allowed, and 0 is a duplicate value. 
I also have the same issue when using 'insert' using CURRENT TIMESTAMP -> which gives a blank column.